# Reduce code for same plotting to screen, pdf and png files?

Tags: r

I want to plot something to my laptop screen, to a pdf file, and to a png file.

So shall I do this:

```
X11()
.. (some plotting)

png("1.png")
.. (some plotting)
dev.off()

pdf("1.pdf")
.. (some plotting)
dev.off()
```

Is there some way to reduce the repetition of the plotting code? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This will work when your desired extension is the same as your device name:

```
extensions<-c('png','pdf')

f<-function(extension){
  get(extension)(paste('1',extension,sep='.'))
  plot(1) # Some plotting...
  dev.off()
}

invisible(sapply(extensions,f))
```

If your extensions were not all the same, then you could do something like:

```
extensions<-c('png','pdf','jpg')
functions<-c(png, pdf, jpeg)

f<-function(extension,func){
  func(paste('1',extension,sep='.'))
  plot(1) # Some plotting...
  dev.off()
}

invisible(mapply(f,extensions,functions))
```

Finally, if you wanted to leave some of the devices on screen, you would make a third vector.

```
extensions<-c('png','pdf','jpg',NA)
functions<-c(png, pdf, jpeg, X11)
on.screen<-c(FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE)

f<-function(extension,func,on.screen){
  if (!on.screen) func() else func(paste('1',extension,sep='.'))
  plot(1) # Some plotting...
  if(!on.screen) dev.off()
}

invisible(mapply(f,extensions,functions,on.screen))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `eval` and `parse` options :

```
filetypes <- c("png","pdf","tiff","jpeg")
filename  <- "myplot"

for(i in 1:length(filetypes))
{
  eval(parse(text=paste(filetypes[i])),env=.GlobalEnv)(file=paste(filename,".",filetypes[i],sep=""))
  plot(x=rnorm(10),y=rnorm(10))
  dev.off()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cool_func <- function(l, dev = TRUE, 
                      path = '/users/rawr/desktop/', name = 'myplot') {

  pdf(file = paste0(path, name, '.pdf'))
  print(l)
  dev.off()

  png(file = paste0(path, name, '.png'))
  print(l)
  dev.off()

  if (dev) {
    if (grepl('apple', sessionInfo()$platform)) quartz()
    # else if (grepl('mingw', sessionInfo()$platform)) windows() # @sourgrapes
    else x11()
  }

  print(l)
}


library(ggplot2)
l <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt, colour = factor(am))) + 
  geom_point() + theme_bw()

cool_func(l)
```

Comment: On Windows, `x11` and `X11` default to `windows` so you don't have to check.

Comment: I just also learned that `dev.new()` will open the default device on your platform, so perhaps you could just use that.